# Extract data from tableau server to r data frame

Tags: r, tableau-api, extract

We currently have a database that can only be accessed via a Tableau front end.

Is it possible with R (or any other means) to be able to extract the underlying data table into csv or txt? I don't really care what it ends up as so long as it is structured and can read into a data frame.

I can see from some looking around that I can use R scripting within Tableau but I cannot see a method to go the other way and pull data out of the Tableau Worksheet.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If its not too much you can export the data from tableau to an excel file. There's also an extraction API that I would suggest you take a look at here https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/extract-api-introduction

Comment: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/save_export_data.html

Comment: If the database can be accessed from Tableau than what is the technical or security controls barrier preventing access from R? Time wld be better spent filing tickets to remove those barriers than hack a closed, expensive, designed-for-lock-in dragon-droppings platform like Tableau.

Comment: Are you using Server or Desktop?